# jQuery Plugins: If I want to call something like $('selector').plugin.group.method(), how can I achieve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some relatively simple jQuery plug-ins, but I am contemplating writing something more advanced in order to keep commonly used methods on the site easily accessible and DRY

For example, I might have something like this for a structure:

```
plugin
- popup
- element
...

=== popup ===
- login
- product
...

=== element ===
- shoppingCart
- loginStatus
...
```

So, to bind a popup login popup event, I'd like to be able to do:
$('#login_button').plugin.popup.login();

What's the best way to do this? Is there a better way of achieving what I want to do?

Cheers,

Comment: Why the plugin namespace? Shouldn't it be enough to just say `$('#login_button').popup.login()`? Namespacing is great in a lot of languages, but not so great in js because scope traversing is slow. I will need to be convinced that it is worth it to have namespaced plugins instead of just calling `$('#login_button').loginPopup()` and `$('#something_else').shoppingCart()`. It may be fun to build from a programming point of view, but I'm not convinced its practical. Don't let me discourage you from having fun though! :)

Comment: Well, if you have separate plugins for "loginPopup" and also "product Popup" and "infoPopup" for example, then the code becomes unDRY. Wouldn't any relatively minor disadvantages in speed be offset by being able to abstract the basics of "popup"?

Comment: You can still abstract the basics without namespacing. `(function($){ function commonMethod(){...} $.fn.loginPopup = function(){commonMethod();}; $.fn.infoPopup = function(){commonMethod();};)(jQuery);` <- sorry, I know thats a pain to read without new lines. Anyway, I'm glad you found something that worked for you. I'm certainly not saying the answers below are *wrong*; I would just prefer something else. But you are right, the difference in speed would likely be minor in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way farhan Ahmad did it was pretty much right... it just needs deeper levels to suit your needs your implementation would look like this:

```
jQuery.fn.plugin = function(){
  //"community" (global to local methods) vars here.
  var selectedObjects = this; //-- save scope so you can use it later

  // return the objects so you can call them as necessary
  return {  
            popup: { //plugin.popup
                    login: function(){ //plugin.popup.login
                         //selectedObjects contains the original scope
                         console.log(selectedObjects);
                    },
                    product: function(){} //plugin.popup.product
            },
            element: { //plugin.element
                    shoppingCart: function() {}, //plugin.element.shoppingCart
                    loginStatus: function() {} //plugin.element.loginStatus
            }
         }
}
```

So now if you call:
`$("#someDiv").plugin.login();` the result will be as expected. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.messagePlugin = function(){
    var selectedObjects = this;
    return {
         saySomething : function(message){
                          $(selectedObjects).each(function(){
                            $(this).html(message);
                          });
                          return selectedObjects; // Preserve the jQuery chainability 
                        },
         anotherAction : function(){
                        //...
                        return selectedObjects;
                        }
           };
}
```

We use it like this:

```
$('p').messagePlugin().saySomething('I am a Paragraph').css('color', 'red');
```

The selected objects are stored in the messagePlugin closure, and that function returns an object that contains the functions associated with the plugin, the in each function you can perform the desired actions to the currently selected objects.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I already found this, and what I'm looking for is the ability to pass an object with prototype properties  so that I can achieve the syntax described above. Any ideas on this?